# Get last occurance of a Lua pattern with string.match

Tags: lua, pattern-matching, lua-patterns

With Lua I am parsing the last occurrence of an XML tag from a large XML string using the pattern:

```
local firstPattern = "<tag>(.-)</tag>"
```

I then used the following code to find every occurrence:

```
local lastMatch
for match in string.gmatch(xmlString, firstPattern) do
  lastMatch = match
end
```

It did not seem very fast so I then tried adding a greedy character to the beginning of my pattern:

```
local secondPattern = ".*<tag>(.-)</tag>"
lastMatch = string.match(xmlString, secondPattern)
```

Printing `os.clock()` before and after the parsing I found the second pattern to be slightly faster but I have to think there is a better pattern to match the last occurrence of the xml tag.

I have also tried a third pattern but it only returns the first instance of the xml tag.

```
local thirdPattern = "<tag>(.-)</tag>.-$"
local firstMatch = string.match(xmlString, thirdPattern)
```

Comment: Try `<tag>((?>[^<]++|<(?!/?tag>))*)</tag>(?=(?>[^<]++|<(?!/?tag))*$)`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte That is not even close to valid for lua patterns.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Sorry but I didn't find a good resource about regex syntax for lua.

Comment: @EtanReisner: has Lua the same regex capabilities as Javascript?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte No. Lua doesn't have regex it has patterns. The [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1) covers them. There are libraries for actual regex support though.

Comment: In general parsing xml/html/etc. with regular expressions is a bad idea. An actual parser is virtually always a better solution.

Comment: Have you tried using LPEG or XML parser?

Comment: Probably, `xmlString:reverse():find('>gat<',1,true)` would be faster.

Comment: @EtanReisner - Why parsing xml with regexp is a bad idea?

Comment: As a rule never parse xml with regex.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff You cannot write a single regular expression that correctly parses XML, since XML is a context-free grammar and RegExs can only parse regular grammars. RegExs are simply not 'powerful' enough. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1758162/646619

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo - That's not correct.  Regexp with backreferences (such as `^(.*)%1$` in Lua) generates non-regular grammar ;-)

Comment: The short answer is [don't do it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Then they aren't regular expressions anymore, technically. It's like saying C can have classes because C++ can. Besides, Lua patterns aren't regexes anyway.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo - So, what is your argument against using Lua patterns for parsing XML?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo - I completely agree that a true XML DOM parser would be the most robust, but I am only interested in this 1 value from the whole file.  In my situation I think a pattern is not too unreasonable since I don't care about the tree structure of the file.  In other situations parsing the entire file into an object model would make the most sense.

Comment: To follow up, I have since actually used an XML parser and it does make it very easy to find the last element since I can get it by `myXMLtable[table.getn(myXMLtable)]`.  I went with the XML parser since I finally needed to look at more than just that one value. Actually building the nested Table in memory from the XML is not too costly.  So thank you @ColonelThirtyTwo for steering me in that direction.

Comment: @blakem `table.getn` is depreciated; use `myXMLtable[#myXMLtable]` instead.